# case and order by - How to specify that something should be shown in the end of the list?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

From:   https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-retrieve-exercise-24.php

Write a SQL query to find all the details of 1970 winners by the ordered to subject and winner name; but the list contain the subject Economics and Chemistry at last.

```
SELECT *
FROM nobel_win
WHERE year=1970 
ORDER BY
 CASE
    WHEN subject IN ('Economics','Chemistry') THEN 1
    ELSE 0
 END ASC,
 subject,
 winner;
```

The CASE here seems to return true if Economics and Chemistry are in subject column.
Which part specifies here that Economics and Chemistry should be shown in the "end"?

Comment: `order by subject in(...) desc`??

Comment: 1 > 0 so those two subjects come after all other subjects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [case](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) expression included here will evaluate to `1` when the `Subject` is 'Economics' or 'Chemistry'. Otherwise it will return a 0.

This is included in the sql query as the first sorting term, to be sorted in `Ascending` order. For the two values of `0` and `1` that are possible, this will sort them in that order: `0` first, then `1`.

In other words, the very first sort will be:

1. All rows where the subject **is not** Economics or Chemistry
2. All rows where the subject **is** Economics or Chemistry

Following this, it sorts by `subject` and `winner` (so as a side effect, in the end of the list, Chemistry will always sort before Economics).

Comment: Case _expression_, not statement.

Comment: @jarlh The mysql manual linked above identifies it as a "statement", hence my usage here of that terminology.

Comment: You are linking to the case _statement_ - which is used for conditional execution of code (e.g. in stored procedures). But here you have the case expression - _which returns a value_, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html.